# Links relacionados as tags em mobile

Tags: suporte, tags

No layout para desktop, quando você clica numa tag aparece a página de perguntas filtrando pela tag selecionado, acima da lista de perguntas tem um quadrado com informações e vários links:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na versão mobile isso não acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que esse links não aparecem na versão mobile?

Existe outra forma de acessar esses links que não seja mudando diretamente a url no navegador?

Comment: No app ou só no site mesmo?

Comment: Não uso o app, não saberia dizer

Comment: Acho que é o óbvio, não? Falta de espaço, estou enganado?

Comment: @Maniero acredito que se esse é o problema, poderia diminuir o texto assim como na versão desktop (que fica com os `...` no final) ou colocar um botão que abra um menu por cima tipo o de notificações. De qualquer forma pelo menos há algum outro jeito de se chegar ao links?