# Layout do site para telas pequenas dando mais prioridade a dados acessórios do que conteúdo

Tags: debate, interface-usuário

Abri o site pelo celular (já que não há manutenção real no aplicativo para iOS e o app está inviável de usar) e abri no modo de visualização do site completo, não na versão desktop. Eis que vejo o seguinte:

[image: Visualização do site completo em dispositivo móvel]

Então me deparei com o seguinte: a informação mais "visualmente relevante" (pelo menos para mim) não foi o título da pergunta, nem suas tags, mas sim pontuação/respostas/visualizações.

Realmente é isso mesmo que é a prioridade dos usuário, essa leitura assim? Ou não era pra ser desse jeito e eu sou um ponto fora da curva por usar o SOpt em um browser de dispositivo móvel?

> Antes que falem que o site tem uma versão mais apropriada para dispositivo móvel que posso selecionar no rodapé, saibam que essa versão é feia, contra intuitiva, ruim e eu quase não acho a "label" de nova pergunta (porque botão sem bordas é label e não aparenta ser clicável, como toda label sem destaque)

Comment: Fique sossegado, todos os nossos problemas de UI acabaram! A rede está reformulando o visual do blockquote! https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919 /s

Comment: E os ícones do editor! Agora ninguém mais usará o snippet para coisas que não são JS ou nem código, ficou bem mai claro.

Comment: Sempre foi ruim, já reclamei de algumas coisas no Metão, o máximo que ganhei foi uns 2 upvotes +2 downvotes e um ou outro comentário dizendo que era uma coisa boa a se resolver e outros comentários dizendo que era frescura minha (não com estas palavras)

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7378/91006). Sempre (desde que entrei na comunidade) usei bastante o SOpt pelo celular pra pesquisar conteúdo no tempo livre e acompanhar perguntas e respostar minhas e de outros que me chamavam a atenção. Apesar de entender que a versão mobile ser mais resumida (ocultar algumas coisas), nunca gostei muito por faltar coisas importantes e mostrar outras menos relevantes

Comment: Opinião: não achei o texto cinza menos destacado que os título azuis.

Comment: @CypherPotato, experiência de uso acaba sendo subjetivo no final. Então você é uma das pessoas que conseguem conviver bem com essa interface. Eu acho ela _annoying_. Fico perturbado com ela =/